# How to output raw JSON from Db

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using common Yii2 `ActiveController` REST implementaion:

```
class ResultController extends ActiveController    
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Result';
    public function actionResultList($id)
    {
        /* @var $modelClass \yii\db\BaseActiveRecord */
        $modelClass = $this->modelClass;

        return new ActiveDataProvider...
```

It works all good for me, except one feature - I've got some JSON stored in my `Result->rawJson` model as string. When I'm outputting it through this controller it gets escaped with slashes, and angular on frontend treats it as a string. The question is how to tell serializer not to serialize several model fields and pass them 'as is'.

I found only this dirty hack to do it, i've added `afterFind` in my model class:

```
public function afterFind()
{
    $this->rawJson= json_decode($this->rawJson);
}
```

I'll appreciate any help on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: it doesn't look dirty as solution to me. I think you made the right choice. it is an array now that you can use anywhere in your app & you can design validators to each of its attributes to verify their content one by one before saving to database instead of making php believe it is just a string, you will just need to convert them back to json within a `beforeSave` method.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you leave the original attribute untouched and create a new attribute with a getter-setter pair. Assuming that your original attribute is called `rawJson`:

```
public function getProcessedJson()
{
    return json_decode($this->rawJson);
}

public function setProcessedJson($value)
{
    $this->rawJson = json_encode($value);
}
```

Then just add `processedJson` to your `fields()` method, and you're good to go.